# Download the text over image using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am working with online photo editor in online project , And i have one problem, I can't download the image , In this project we can add the text over the image, and that texts are editable texts, and after editing the text i can't download the image , I need to download the afer adding text over image, Please help me, (Sorry- I am not good in english).

Comment: Post your question with whatever code you have done. With text, we can just make castle in the air.

Comment: "_i can't download the image_" is not a very good description of your problem. Do you get any errors in the logs? Does the image exist? How is this related to CSS3?

Answer (score -3):

plz draw image by server side language like php online may class are available that convert html to PDF or image